# How to boot into Windows Boot Manager from GRUB?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I recently dual-booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu. When I start my computer, the GRUB operating system list starts up. Ubuntu works fine, but if I try to select Windows Boot Manager, I get an error. Is it possible that the Boot Manager might have been deleted? If so, how do I fix it?

Attached is photos of the error and the master boot order.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turn secure boot off, and Windows should boot through grub.  This is bug # 1091464.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464
You can add yourself to the "this bug affects 87 people" by clicking on the yellow button after the question.

---

To continue to use secure boot, either use Rod Smith's suggestion below for a different bootloader, or simply use the EFI menu (some function key at power-up) to select Windows directly, skipping grub.

Comment: If you want to keep using Secure Boot, a workaround is to install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) This will require some extra hoop-jumping, though, since you'll need to install a Secure Boot key for rEFInd (either the key I generated or one you generate locally, depending on how you install). This is a bit awkward to describe, but not really all that hard. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html#installation) for details. It's likely to be easier to disable Secure Boot.